# New products not showing in category frontend Magento 2.3.7-p3

Tags: product, frontend, indexer, new-products, magento2.3.7

Before you dismiss this kindly read the details. I have come across several issues but none provide a solution to my question.

My products do not show in the frontend of the store.

- They are visible when I visit them directly in the format: http://baseURL/catalog/product/view/id/ but they do not show in the categories frontend. The product image shows along with the add to cart button.
- Database View: The view (inventory_stock_1) is in the database.
- Product setup: is enabled, in stock, default stock is over 18 in the product grid, Product Salable Quantity shows that default stock is 18.
- Source/Stock: items have been assigned to inventory source. Stock is assigned to source.
- I am managing inventory with the inventory configurations
- I have even gone into the display settings for the categories. Display mode is static block and products. Anchor is YES. Available Product Listing Sort By: USE All
- CLI Commands: Magento commands have been run but nothing. indexer, cache.

Below is the result of bin/magento indexer:reindex

```
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1478 InnoDB: Tablespace `yx_gtt` cannot contain TEMPORARY tables., query was: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gtt_catalog_product_index_eav_temp` LIKE `gtt_catalog_product_index_eav_tmp`
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1478 InnoDB: Tablespace `yx_gtt` cannot contain TEMPORARY tables., query was: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gtt_catalog_product_index_price_temp` LIKE `gtt_catalog_product_index_price_tmp`
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
```

Even with all the above, I get an error: *We can't find products matching the selection..* when I visit the frontend. The categories show as links in the menu but the products under them are not displayed

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: By symptomatic it's more looks like you have wrong index data. Need to check each item step by step. For example, what data are you have in `url_rewrite` for `target_path='catalog/product/view/id/1'`, where 1 is product id? Is product accessible by it URL rewrite? Check `catalog_category_product_index_store1` where 1 is store id? What is result of CLI command `bin/magento index:reindex`?

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk I have edited the question with the results of the CLI command and the information when I use the the product id directly

Comment: The root cause of issue is generating index. What is MySQL version are you use? I found few the same errors like [General error: 1478 InnoDB](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/SQLSTATE-HY000-General-error-1478-when-trying-to-reindex-or/td-p/447457). You can try to apply following patch [change create temporary table](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magemojo/m2-patches/main/framework-adapter-pdo.patch). See reference [MySQL 8 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html)

Comment: I have switched to elasticsearch because I kept getting a warning that MySQL Catalog search was deprecated. Elasticsearch is hosted on another server and I place the server hostname, port, username and password so Magento can connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

The same logic in patch [change create temporary table](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magemojo/m2-patches/main/framework-adapter-pdo.patch) described as solution in question [Product EAV index exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1478 InnoDB: Tablespace `innodb_system` cannot contain TEMPORARY tables.,](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/330098/product-eav-index-exception-sqlstatehy000-general-error-1478-innodb-tables)