# Inventory management not automatically changing to 'out of stock' (is there Patches List for Magento 2)

Tags: product, frontend, inventory, indexer, magento2.3.7

I have faced issue after issue with the Magento 2 software that entails me having to do patch after patch.

My most recent issue is with the inventory feature. I have turned on inventory management, run cron, and memory/storage looks good. But here is the issue.

Assume I have twenty (20) pieces of one item, say hats. Several people keep buying until that number gets to zero (I have set ‘out of stock’ to zero). The system is meant to automatically put this item to ‘out of stock’ thereby making it impossible to appear as available to add to cart. Now this does not happen. And this is just one scenario.

Assume now, there are two (2) items. Hats and shoes. There are twenty (20) pieces of hats and twenty (20) pieces of shoes. Assume that the hats have been sold out and the shoes are available. The system does not disable the add to cart button for the item that is not available, and the user is unaware. Now the user goes ahead and adds a shoe and a hat to the cart. At the point of checkout, the system throws an error simply because there is an item in the backend that is not available in stock but is in the cart of the user. In the first place the user should not have been able to add the item to cart because from inventory it is not available!

The ideal expected behaviour is that if the inventory is managed by Magento, once an item is at zero level in the backend, on the frontend/store the ‘add to cart’ button is replaced with the ‘out of stock’ notice and the user cannot click on it talk less of adding to cart.

Now I ask, to make it easier for existing and new Magento 2 users, is there a list of all patches (patches list) for the Magento 2 system? I saw this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fNjgs1p42A&t=384s) material where the speaker directed that few patches need to happen in order for the Magento 2 software to work optimally while using it on your server. Personally, I had an issue and posted a [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/356532/new-products-not-showing-in-category-frontend-magento-2-3-7-p3/356534). Is it possible to have a list of ALL the patches that need to happen before a store can go live? I mean like a checklist of patches that need to happen immediately after installation of the Magento 2 software. What code needs to be edited and in what files?

Answer (score 0):

If your Magento 2 store's inventory management is not automatically changing to 'out of stock' when products are sold, there could be several reasons for this. Here are a few things you can check:

1. Check the product's inventory settings
   Verify that the product's inventory settings are set up correctly. Ensure that the 'Manage Stock' option is enabled and the 'Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock' is set to a value that makes sense for your business. You can find these options under the 'Inventory' tab on the product edit page in the Magento Admin panel.
2. Check the stock status of the product
   Verify that the stock status of the product is correct. You can check this by going to the product edit page in the Magento Admin panel and looking for the 'Stock Status' field under the 'Inventory' tab. If the stock status is set to 'In Stock', then the product will not be marked as 'out of stock' even if the quantity on hand is zero.
3. Check the cron jobs
   Ensure that the Magento cron jobs are set up correctly and running as expected. The inventory management system relies on the cron jobs to check the inventory levels and update the stock status of products accordingly. You can check the cron jobs by running the bin/magento cron:check command in the command line.
4. Check for any customizations or extensions
   If you have any customizations or extensions installed that affect the inventory management system, ensure that they are working correctly and not interfering with the automatic stock status updates.

Comment: Thanks for the input Gayalal. Your number 2 point is driving me wild. Are you saying that it should be out of stock while inventory is being managed by the system? Because my understanding is that if I have the product then it should be in stock so the system can switch it automatically if it gets to zero